# React-router and bower: Is there a build step to produce global dir?

Tags: reactjs

Where does bower_components/react-router/build/global/ReactRouter.js

come from? Is there some build step?

I don't see what creates the global dir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory has changed in recent versions of React Router, but you can see [in the `package.json` for the project](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v0.12.4/package.json#L13) that they explicitly built to `build/global` in the past:

```
"scripts": {
    "build-global": "rm -rf build/global && NODE_ENV=production webpack modules/index.js build/global/ReactRouter.js && NODE_ENV=production COMPRESS=1 webpack modules/index.js build/global/ReactRouter.min.js && echo \"gzipped, the global build is `gzip -c build/global/ReactRouter.min.js | wc -c` bytes\"",
```